# Set of definable real numbers?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, foundations

Is there a set theory at least as strong as $KP\omega$ which has as a theorem that there is a set $\mathbb{D}$ of precisely the definable real numbers?

Comment: How do you *define* "definable real number"? The obvious approach is via truth, which isn't definable.

Comment: Yes, I now recall Joel David Hamkins had some on this which entailed indefinability in *ZF*.

I had in mind definable by a first order condition as in the subset axiom.

Comment: Again, *how do you define* "definable by a first order condition"?

Comment: The subset axiom already uses the notion of a first order definable condition, which is sometimes called a Skolem condition. Basically it is a condition expressed using only the set theoretic language. Weyl was onto the same thing earlier, and both were motivated by making Zermi’s theory more precise.

Comment: "The subset axiom already uses the notion of a first order definable condition" Not really - it's a *scheme* of axioms, one for each formula. That's not helpful for what you're trying to do here, since you need a *single* axiom treating all possible definitions at once.

Comment: @Noah Schweber You’re right! We would indeed need a truth predicate for such a construction, and cannot have one I guess for strong theories. This is what Hamkins was onto, I think. But perhaps we may have one for weaker theories?

Comment: Well, Tarski applies to any reasonably strong theory whatsoever, so the only hope would be something like the overkill situation I indicated - where the objects you want to define all happen to have simple definitions.

Comment: You are right again. The Diagonal Lemma makes it impossible. So such constructions cannot be had in classical style set theories. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

*This is only a partial answer to the question.*

---

The immediate problem here is phrasing the question properly. The predicate "is a definable real number" is **not definable** in any natural way, so it doesn't even make sense in general to ask whether "Every real is definable" (or "For every set, the set of definable reals in that set is a set") is a theorem of a given system. (And note that if it did, the question would be trivial: ZFC proves that $\mathbb{R}$ exists and has the full Separation scheme, so *if* we could refer to definability then ZFC would prove "there is a set of all definable reals.")

*Contrast this with e.g. the construction of the $L$-hierarchy: definability in a **"small structure"** is perfectly definable - e.g. the predicate "$x$ is definable in $M$" is definable - but definability in the universe poses a problem. Also contrast this with [ordinal definability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_definable_set), which surprisingly **is** definable after all.*

The only way around this problem I see is to go for an overkill solution. While definability itself is not definability, $\Sigma_n$-definability *is* definable for each fixed $n$. We would therefore be quite happy if "definable" and "$\Sigma_n$-definable" were to coincide for reals. This can happen - for example, in $L_{\omega_1^{CK}}$ the $L$-ordering itself is definable by a single formula and has ordertype $\omega_1^{CK}$, so each real $r$ can be defined as "The unique real in the $\alpha$th place of the $L$-ordering of the universe" for an appropriate computable (hence definable) well-ordering $\alpha$. *(In fact, note that this gives more generally that every element of $L_{\omega_1^{CK}}$ is definable by a $\Sigma_n$ formula for some fixed small $n$ - at a glance, $n=3$ should be enough.)*

Of course as you observe this by itself doesn't solve the problem: we want the *class* of $\Sigma_n$-definable reals to be a *set* (and this fails in $L_{\omega_1^{CK}}$, in particular). I think the natural question at this point is:

> Is there some natural number $n$ such that the theory $KP\omega$ +  "$\mathbb{R}$ exists" + "Every real is $\Sigma_n$-definable" is consistent?

**I believe this is the "right" precisiation of your question** (although unfortunately I don't have an answer at the moment).

Comment: I don’t see that this settles whether there is a *set* of the definable real numbers.

Comment: @FrodeAlfsonBjørdal You're right, here the definable reals form a definable class (namely all of $\mathbb{R}$) but not a set. Let me see if I can fix that ...

Comment: I like your precisiation and hope it can work.

Comment: So may I interpret the last two as $\exists x(\forall y(y\in x\leftrightarrow y  \ is \ [ a \ \Sigma_n-definable\ real \ number] ))?$